# How to open an Android application from a webpage

Tags: android, android-intent, maui, intentfilter

I'm currently trying to open an Android application from a webpage. And to pass two parameters.

I went for the intent solution as it seems that custom scheme are not recommended, and in this case, I don't need a deeplink.

Currently, in debug, the only thing that happens is that my intent url is opened inside chrome and display a white page.
It never opens the application.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.MyApp">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
        
        <activity
            android:name="com.MyApp.activity.MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="MyApp">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.MyApp.LAUNCH"></action>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
                <data android:scheme="MyScheme" android:host="MyHost" android:path="/"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

This is my javascript:

```
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
            var uri = "intent://MyApp#Intent;scheme=MyScheme;action=com.MyApp.LAUNCH;package=com.MyApp;S.p=" + p + ";S.c=" + c + ";end";
            window.open(uri);
        }
```

I've seen a lot of way of doing this and tried a lot of things, but I don't get what is the good way to do with API 33.

I tried to use "intent:#Intent", "intent://#Intent", I tried with and without data property under activity, I tried my own scheme "MyScheme://".

I would like to avoid using deeplink as I would like to keep my website accessible without launching the app (different goals).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check [Handling Android App Link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) documentation.

Basically, to open the app you need to specify some specific scheme, for example:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyMapActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="myapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And the link to open will be: `myapp://anypath_here?param1=value1&param2=value2`

Try to use a unique scheme, otherwise, you will have an 'Open with..' dialog opening if another app can open it.

Comment: I've read that it was not recommended anymore to use custom schemes.

Reddit, for example, use the syntaxe intent://

Comment: you can use `intent://` but then you need to set `<data android:scheme="intent" />`. When you create a link it should be like: `<scheme>://<host>/<path>?<query>`. You can see as an example opening the map app where you share location data: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending#view-map

Comment: I've tried debuging with adb. My deeplink seems to be working. It also works if I send the link through Telegram, but it doesn't work if I'm already in a webbrowser. Does it ring a bell?

Comment: I think it depends on the browser you use, because intent-filter works on the system level, but the browser itself needs to open links with Intent, and you should see a dialog like here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending#AppChooser My guess, that your browser opens a link internally without firing intent. Try to open the link on another browser (better system default browser or chrome if not installed).

btw: you can also check the Intent firing in Logcat

Answer (score 0):

To enable link handling verification for your app, add intent filters that match the following format:

```
<!-- Make sure you explicitly set android:autoVerify to "true". -->
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <!-- If a user clicks on a shared link that uses the "http" scheme, your
         app should be able to delegate that traffic to "https". -->
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />

    <!-- Include one or more domains that should be verified. -->
    <data android:host="..." />
</intent-filter>
```

More information you can refer to [Verify Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#manual-verification).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was already doing something similar. I've been able to debug with adb, my deeplink work.

It works if I click on it through telegram. But if I open the link directly in Chrome, it doesn't work. Do you have any insight about this? I haven't seen anything like this in the documentation.

Comment: When you clicks a deep link, a disambiguation dialog might appear. This dialog allows you to select one of multiple apps, including your app, that can handle the given deep link.

Comment: So if you open the link directly in Chrome it will work as a website and it can not recognize it as your App link.